# How to show $\text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

We're given the hint that to prove the isomorphism, define the mapping $L : \text{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q}) \to \mathbb{Q}$ by $f \mapsto f(1).$

Then I don't know how to show it is well defined. For if $f(1)=g(1)$, then how do I know $f$ and $g$ agree on all other elements in $\mathbb{Q}$?

It's easy to show it is $\mathbb{Z}$-linear and injective. I haven't reached the point to think about how to show it is surjective.

Comment: Note that $q\;f(p/q) =  p \;f(1)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I thought you could pull out only $p$ since $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Oh you edited your comment.

Comment: Well-defined should be easy: Are there any choices being made in the definition of $L$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping $L\colon f\mapsto f(1)$ *is* well defined, no problem with this. It's also easy to see it's a group homomorphism $L\colon\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Q})\to\mathbb{Q}$.

The problem is showing $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Injectivity: suppose $L(f)=f(1)=0$. Then, for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f(a)=0$. If $b\ne0$, then $0=f(a)=bf(a/b)$, so $f(a/b)=0$. Therefore $f$ is the zero map.

Surjectivity: let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Define $g\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ by $g(a)=aq$. Can you extend this to a homomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$?

Hint: define $f(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{1}{b}g(a)=\frac{a}{b}q$. This should be checked to be well defined.

Note: since the map $x\mapsto qx$ is obviously a linear map of  $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, there is no real need to check about well definedness of $f$ above. Indeed $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity implies $\mathbb{Z}$-linearity.

Comment: But I'm confused about how the map $\phi$ is well defined to begin with. How do we know $f(1) = g(1)$ implies $f = g$.

Comment: I meant $L$, not $\phi$.

Comment: @J.Doe That is one-to-one, not well-definedness.

Comment: @J.Doe There is no doubt $L$ is well defined: it acts on a particular $f$ by associating to it the rational number $f(1)$. The property “$f(1)=g(1)$ implies $f=g$” is injectivity.

Comment: Thank you so much. As for surjectivity, can we say since $g$ is clearly well-defined, then so is $f$. Then, given $q \in mathbb{Q}, L(f) = f(1) = g(1) = q?

Comment: Thank you so much. As for surjectivity, can we say since gg is clearly well-defined, then so is ff. Then, given $q \in mathbb{Q}, L(f) = f(1) = g(1) = q$?

Comment: @J.Doe You have to check that, if $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a'}{b'}$, then $\frac{a}{b}q=\frac{a'}{b'}q$, which is essentially obvious. Also checking that $f$ is a homomorphism is straightforward.

Comment: Can we say since $g$ is clearly well-defined, then so is $f$. Then, given $q \in \mathbb{Q}, L(f) = f(1) = g(1) = q$?

Comment: @egreg Sorry to bother you, can you explain if there is any particular reason we map $f$ to $f(1)$? I know it's well defined, but wouldn't $f(2)$, say, also work?

Comment: @J.Doe Yes, it would work. You can use any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $q\ne0$, instead of $1$.